# MySQL join statement

Tags: mysql, join

Could anyone offer some help please?!...

I have an sql database table called meals and another database table called menu:

```
meals (id, name, description, cost)
menu (date, option1, option2)
```

The idea being that there are 2 meal choices in a given day, for example:

```
09/02/16  meal id 1 OR meal id 8
10/02/16  meal id 4 OR meal id 12
```

I want to use a join statement similar to this:

```
select * from meals JOIN menu ON meals.id = menu.option1 AND meals.id=menu.option2
```

but every time I run this I get an error message, saying table alias not unique.

I want the final output to display:

```
date: option 1 meal id, name, cost AND option 2 meal id, name, cost
```

e.g.

```
09/02/16 - 1(id) Chicken curry £2.50 + 8 (id) Roast Beef £3.00
10/02/19 4 (id) Baked potato £2.50 + 12 (id) Soup/Sandwiches £2.75
```

Comment: Try this `select * from meals mea INNER JOIN menu men ON mea.id = men.option1 OR mea.id=men.option2`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - They also probably meant `OR`, not `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` rather than `AND`, because you want to match either option, not both in a single meal. This can also be done using `IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM meals
JOIN menu ON meals.id IN (menu.option1, menu.option2)
```

If you want to get both meals for a date in the same row, use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT menu.date, GROUP_CONCAT(' + ', CONCAT_WS(' ', meals.id, meals.name, meals.cost)) AS options
FROM meals
JOIN menu ON meals.id IN (menu.option1, menu.option2)
GROUP BY menu.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Since menu is the entity that you are fetching, and getting the details of each meal based on what's in the menu, it makes sense to start with SELECTing FROM menu.

Option1 and Option2 are two distinct entities, so you'll need to join the `meals` table two different times instead of using `AND` or `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM menu 
LEFT JOIN meals AS m1 ON option1 = m1.id 
LEFT JOIN meals AS m2 ON option2 = m2.id
```