# LEFT JOIN with relative value from main query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I've two tables: **users** and **friendship**. For example:

**users** table:

```
id | user  | email   | website
1  | Igor  | i@o.com | stack.com
2  | Lucas | a@i.com | overflow.com
3  | John  | j@w.com | www.com
```

**friendship** table (when `status = 2` means that they are friends):

```
id | friend1 | friend2 | status
1  | Igor    | John    | 2
2  | Lucas   | Igor    | 2
3  | John    | Lucas   | 2
```

And I do the following to select the friends (of which `$user` is the current user logged in):

```
SELECT friend1, friend2 
FROM friendship 
WHERE (friend1 = '$user' OR friend2 = '$user') AND status = 2
```

But I also want to select the user data in the **users** table, therefore, I would do:

```
SELECT friend1, friend2 
FROM friendship 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON user = **friend** 
WHERE (friend1 = '$user' OR friend2 = '$user') AND status = 2
```

in ON clause above, I left asterisks in the word **friend** for you look where is my doubt. I want to select only the data in the table **users** other than the current user logged (`$user`), I know I should use to verify that CASE is equal to the logged in user but I don't know how to do this in this case.

Comment: You may want to join the users table twice, one to friend1 and one to friend2. See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35304655/225134

Comment: @fredrover if I use your solution. How to do with the data in `foreach`?

Comment: I see what you mean: each time through the loop you would have data on 2 users. But one would always be the same, because it is the one you queried for. As you said, you don't want that user's data, so that would probably be better solved in the query itself, and my suggestion may not end up being helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with a simple `JOIN` that just includes your logic:

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    U.user,
    U.email,
    U.website
FROM
    Friendship F
INNER JOIN Users U ON
    (U.user = F.friend1 AND F.friend1 <> '$user') OR
    (U.user = F.friend2 AND F.friend2 <> '$user')
WHERE
    F.friend1 = '$user' OR F.friend2 = '$user'
```

Comment: Not worked. Returned only one result (of my table `friendships` with two rows) where the user logged is the friend2.

Comment: I just ran it with several tests and all came back correctly. I would check how you copied it over.

Comment: I will do more tests tomorrow with you query again, so I will comment the result

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use

```
select * from user where 
user in (
    select friends1 from friendship where friend2='$user' and status=2
    union all
    select friends2 from friendship where friend1='$user' and status=2
)
```

I added left join example

```
select u.* from (
    select friends1 f from friendship where friend2='$user' and status=2
    union all
    select friends2 f from friendship where friend1='$user' and status=2) a
left join user u on a.f=u.user
```

Comment: joins are far more efficient than subqueries

Comment: Any suggestion (example), @Dagon ?

Comment: Kiro can easily convert the `IN()` into a `JOIN`. The `UNION ALL` might be faster than the `OR`, simply don't forget to add the check on the `status` field.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. The result of 2 query may differ if some users are present in friendship but not in user table.

Comment: @kiro how to do in `foreach` with the data?

Comment: what do u mean foreach? Do you mean the field name? field name should be the same if you use star to query

Answer (score 2):

This works with your sample data (assuming you want user info for both friends in a friendship):

```
SELECT f.friend1, u1.id, u1.email, u1.website, f.friend2, u2.id, u2.email, u2.website
FROM friendship f
INNER JOIN users u1
ON f.friend1 = u1.user 
INNER JOIN users u2
ON f.friend2 = u2.user
WHERE (friend1 = '$user' OR friend2 = '$user')
AND f.status = 2
```

Comment: I want user info only for the user that isn't the current logged (`$user`)